# Jenkins pipeline to change appssettings.json file and build according to the environment

Tags: jenkins

I had a requirment to build a console application, but i need to change some values in appssettings.json file according to the environment and then build it. I am new to jenkins and want to know how to acheive this.

for dev change values in json file and build it -> for test again change the json values and build it -> till prod

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in multiple ways for example (the common idea between these is to check the incoming branch):

> You might find better ways to do it but you can use this as a start.

- Using `bash`, `jq`, `sponge` through `sh` step:

  1. Create a json file as a template like the following (consider keeping this file in a version control to clone every build)

     ```
     # settings.json
     {
       environment: 'ENVIRONMENT_NAME',
       appVersion: 'APP_VERSION'
     }
     ```
  2. Check the branch name value through `if` condition and update the template according to the branch value

     ```
     jq '.environment = "branch_name"' settings.json|sponge settings.json
     ```
  3. Use the customized settings.json in your application's code
- Using [Config File Provider Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin) which can be used inside the Jenkins pipeline as the following (also update it based on the branch name)

  ```
  configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'FILE_ID', targetLocation: 'FILE_LOCATION')]) {}
  ```
- Check if the application framework can make use of environment variables.